# FileSystemWatcher fires as many number of files in the folder

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I encounter some weird behavior with the FileSystemWatch.    Below is my C# code:

```
FileSystemWatcher fs = new FileSystemWatcher(_sd);
fs.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
fs.Filter = "*.*";
fs.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(fs_Changed);
fs.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fs_Changed);
fs.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(fs_Renamed);
fs.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fs_Changed);
fs.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(fs_Error);
fs.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
fs.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

I do have my event handler as:

```
static void fs_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Folder changed", "Notification", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Nothing is more or less.

When I run the window form app, it watches the folder.   Supposedly in my folder, I do have 3 **existing** files.  Now, I add one more file to it, the MessageBox.Show(...) calls **4 times**????!!!!     Basicaly, it calls as many times as the number of files in that directory!!!!???

Am I doing something wrong?   It looks basic enough to me and I wonder why I get 4 calls?

Question:  Is there a way to just have it call once?  Is there work around on it?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just getting multiple events for the same file? For example a `Created` then a `Changed`?

Comment: I am positive, DavidG.  Just right click and create a dummy text file.   However, the events fire as many files in the directory!!!!  That is super weird.  

Please advise.

Comment: Have you checked `e.ChangeType` and `e.Name` in each event to see what actually happened?